# How to logout from vk api on ios?

Tags: ios, vk

I've integrated login with vk button in my ios app. And I want to add an ability to switch account.

I've tried to run network request to `http://api.vk.com/oauth/logout`. But it outputs `wrong logout hash`.

I used this code:

```
let logoutUrl = "http://api.vk.com/oauth/logout"

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: logoutUrl)!,
        cachePolicy:.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData,
        timeoutInterval:60.0)
        let responseData = try! NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil)
```

Also I tried to clear NSDefaults, after logout:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.removeObjectForKey("VKAccessUserId")
        defaults.removeObjectForKey("VKAccessToken")
        defaults.removeObjectForKey("VKAccessTokenDate")
        defaults.synchronize()
```

And to clear cookies:

```
let storage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
        for cookie in storage.cookies {
            let domainName = cookie.domain
            let domainRange = domainName.rangeOfString("vk.com")

            if(domainRange.length > 0) {
                storage.deleteCookie(cookie)
            }
        }
```

And nothing helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Should call `VKSdk.forceLogout()`